# software.amazon.awssdk.core.exception.SdkClientException Profile file contained no credentials for profile 'my-queue': ProfileFile(profiles=[])

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I am trying to access SQS queue and have profile my-queue for which i have created credentials and config file under ~/.aws folder.

This works fine in my windows machine with credentials and config file under username folder but it is throwing error on a Linux system which is an EC2 instance.

I am using ProfileCredentialsProvider.create("my-queue") to build client

Answer (score 0):

For EC2 instance, best practice is not to use IAM profile.

1. Create instance role in IAM console with SQS permission
2. Attach that instance role to your instance
3. Don't specify any credentials in your instance.

Have a look at [AWS guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) for more information.